# Problem establishing connection over Python Modbus TCP to a Mitsubishi Inverter

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, pymodbus3, pymodbustcp

I am trying to establish a Modbus connection from a laptop to a Mitsubishi inverter (FR A-800 E series) (the manual for this connection can be found [here][1])

I am using pymodbus and I can establish a connection, but the problem comes when I try to read a register.

I know I am connection because doing something like:

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.15.10', 502)
client.connect()
```

results in a

```
True
```

response. Also, if I just print `client` it returns the details of the connection, which makes me confident the connection is properly establish. But, whenever I try to read a register (which I am confident exists, since it appears in the manual) :

```
result=client.read_holding_registers(9,1,1)
print(result)
```

I would obtain:

```
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)
```

and if I try again,

```
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/unable to decode response.
```

Does anyone have any idea? I have tried with a bunch of addresses for the registers, I have tried including not including the 1,1) part when reading the register and got no luck.

[1]: https://dl.mitsubishielectric.com/dl/fa/document/manual/inv/ib0600628eng/ib0600628engd.pdf)

Comment: The manual says "Unit identifier Fixed to 255" so I'd try that (`client.read_holding_registers(9,1,255)`). Many ModbusTCP devices ignore this but some don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! Shouldn't that have stopped the communication in the first place?

Comment: No, the unit ID is sent with each request (so you can establish a connection and then communicate with different units attached to that gateway).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and report back.

Comment: Sorry - from your comment I assumed you had checked and this helped (hence raising the answer to close things off). No worries - will wait to hear (with the info available there is some guesswork involved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the manual says "Unit identifier Fixed to 255" so use that (`client.read_holding_registers(9,1,255)`).

Some ModbusTCP devices ignore this but sometimes you need to specify the correct value in order to get a response.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and report back